# Spring MVC - Executing an Oracle Stored Procedure using java?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I have a JDBCTemplate connection and a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate connection variable between my Spring MVC application and an Oracle database. I also have a stored procedure in the Oracle database that takes either a 0 or 1 as an input parameter, and does not return anything upon completion.

I need help understanding how to execute this stored procedure.

Eventually I will need to send this execution to a thread to complete without having the user to sit and wait, but I need to get this step first.

I have looked at the other questions on the site for help and it feels like the explanations aren't giving me anything I can work with. So I need any advise that can be offered.

All I have is this so far which isn't even correct:

```
    public void processRetrosToEpay() throws SQLException{
        //CallableStatement cs = spaeJDBCTemplate.prepareCall("RP_RETRO_PROCESS(?)");
        //cs.execute();
    }
```

Comment: Even the One which is not working needs a parameter passed to it `cstmt.setString(1, "parameter");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out when another developer came back from vacation.

this is the solution we came up with:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(spaeJDBCTemplate).withCatalogName("SCHEMA1").withProcedureName("PROCESS");
    Map<String, Integer> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    inParamMap.put("process", 0);
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
    try{
        simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Error ", e);
    }
```

I hope this help others who have encoutered this.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Java `CallableStatement` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), you should use this syntax:

```
"{?= call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}"
"{call <procedure-name>[(<arg1>,<arg2>, ...)]}"
```

And per the [`OracleCallableStatement` API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html), you can use either the syntax above, or this Oracle-specific syntax:

```
"begin proc (?,?); end;"
"begin ? := func(?,?); end;"
```